# Circle animation when area become touched

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry

I try to create a animation where a circle become moved by a touchevent:

```
function initi() {
    console.log('init');
    // Get a reference to our touch-sensitive element
    var touchzone = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    // Add an event handler for the touchstart event
    touchzone.addEventListener("mousedown", startTouch, false);
    // You need mouseup to capture the stop event                           
    touchzone.addEventListener("mouseup", stopTouch, false);
}

function startTouch(event) {
    // You can access the event here too..
    // But for demo I will only get the current Time

    startTime = new Date().getTime();
}

function stopTouch(event) {
    // Get a reference to our coordinates div
    var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    // Write the coordinates of the touch to the div



    if (event.pageX < x * 100 && event.pageY > y * 10) {
        // Calculate the duration, only if needed
        var duration = new Date().getTime() - startTime;

        bally -= 0.005 * duration; // use duration

        }
    else if ( event.pageX > x * 100)    {

    }


    // I hope bally if defined in the outer scope somewhere ;)                     
    console.log(event, x, bally);
    draw();
}
```

So my question is how can I make the bally smaller when this area: `event.pageX < x * 100 && event.pageY > y * 10` become touched, after `bally -= 0.005 * duration;` become executed? I try it with arrays to save if its touched and then give it to update function and know that localstorage and cookies would work too but I think thats not the best solution. Any hints to realize that?

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a2qr1k5/1/)